# Rubygem to notify Rake Task is finished

Tags: rubygems, rake, rake-task

Is there any Rubygem to send an email or push notification after a certain Rake Task is finished? It's good if there is one as I usually do multi tasking and forget to check if a process of Rake task is finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're on a Mac, use Growl (http://growl.info/) and the growl gem (https://rubygems.org/gems/growl). You will need to install the growlnotify extra (http://growl.info/extras.php/#growlnotify) to enable growl notifications from the command line--something the gem depends on.

At this point you can add some Ruby in your Rakefile to notify yourself. Example:

```
notification = Growl.new
notify_ok 'Deployment successful'
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I find that this is easier (ubuntu):

```
rake whatever_task; notify-send "whatever_task finished with status $?"
```

On OSX, you'll want to use `growlnotify` instead of `notify-send` (I think)